# Converting a nested Map of ArrayList to a single line using Stream API - Java Functional Programming

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I'm still not good with functional programming and therefore need help. Could you please help me write the same thing using stream API.

Thanks in advance.

```
Map<Integer, Map<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>> map = new TreeMap<>();
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
for(Map.Entry<Integer, Map<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>> ele: map.entrySet()){
    ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Map.Entry<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> ent: ele.getValue().entrySet()){
        temp.addAll(ent.getValue());
    }
    result.add(temp);
}
```

This is my approach. But there are some errors.

```
System.out.println(
    map.values()
        .stream()
        .map(ins -> { 
            ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
            ins.values().stream().forEach(temp::addAll);
            return temp;
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: The fact you are receiving a `cannot find symbol` leads me to believe that you have not correctly imported your packages.

Comment: `import java.util.stream.Collectors;`

Comment: @gcoderx Have you tried my answer???

Comment: I demand the reopening of the question. The question is not at all related to the question it has made to be associated with. It was a simple question of converting a nested hashmap of ArrayList to a line using stream API. Well, I have posted the solution in the question itself if somebody needs help with this. There were learning aspects of this but has been marked duplicate . I disagree but the decision is acceptable.

Comment: @YassinHajaj I have removed the error part. The question is all about conversion and not the imports. Even after the correct imports, it did not seem to work. Well, I have the solution ready now. So if you could please review it again, it'll be nice.

Comment: ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result = map.values().stream()
                        .map(ins -> ins.values().stream()
                                    .flatMap(List::stream)
                                    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)))
                        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
        return result; -- answer

Answer (score -1):

You can try flatMap

Also instead of directly using **`temp::addAll`**, you need to try as below.

## **`Update1`**

```
    System.out.println(
                    map.entrySet()
                            .stream()
                            .flatMap(ins -> ins.getValue().entrySet().stream()
                                    .map(integerListEntry -> integerListEntry.getValue())).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

## Update2

```
System.out.println(
                Arrays.asList(map.entrySet().stream()
                        .flatMap(ins -> ins.getValue().entrySet().stream()
                                .flatMap(integerListEntry->integerListEntry.getValue().stream())).collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

You can also create Method Reference as mentioned below. Here i had created method name with **`flatteringInnerMap`** and simply calling it by method reference.

```
   System.out.println(
            map.entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .flatMap(ins -> ins.getValue().entrySet().stream()
                            .flatMap(Sample::flatteringInnerMap)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
}

private static Stream<? extends Integer> flatteringInnerMap(Map.Entry<Integer, List<Integer>> integerListEntry) {
    return integerListEntry.getValue().stream();
}
```

More about flatMap you will get idea [**`here.`**](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stream-flatmap-java-examples/)

One more point i want to add here.

> I recommend using **`"List"`** instead of **`"ArrayList"`** on the
> left side when creating list objects. It's better to pass around the
> interface **`"List"`** because then if later you need to change to
> using something like Vector (e.g. you now need synchronized lists),
> you only need to change the line with the "new" statement. No matter
> what implementation of list you use, e.g. **`Vector or ArrayList`**,
> you still always just pass around List.

This will help you.

Comment: Hi, I tried this. I wanted the result to be a nested ArrayList. But the output of this gives me a single list. Please look into this. Thank you very much for helping.
And yeah, for the part that mentions that we generally use the interface in place of the class, I could not do much. This was required in the problem.  But it was a good thing you told me about.

Comment: @gcoderx Try updated answer.

Comment: Hi, tried. This time it has not merged values of the inner hashmap. Please see the updated question where I have posted the solution. The post has been closed and so cannot answer. If possible, please simplify it a bit more. Thanks again for giving your time.

Comment: @gcoderx mine first answer is same only. You just need to create List from it.

Comment: Yeah, I see. Thanks

Comment: @gcoderx I had added updated answer. Instead of creating temporary list and adding all elements inside of it, you can implement using `flatMap` and collecting that `List as List`